# How to tell Babeljs to ignore certain requires?

Tags: babeljs, aws-lambda

I am using babeljs to transpile my AWS Lambda functions to ES5 because AWS Lambda doesn't support the ES6 yet.

I include aws-sdk into my code with require('aws-sdk').

This module is available by default by AWS Lambda and it should not be uploaded.

How do I tell babel not to include this module?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was a webpack problem not babeljs.